# Unix executable changes to TextEdit document when copied

Tags: java, macos, copy, executable, apache-commons

I have the following script, of which you can see below. The function of this Java script is to copy a Mac app, of which is placed in the same folder as the java program. It first finds the path of the folder, which the app and java program is in. It then copies all the content to the documents folder on the Mac device. When that is done it is then supposed to run that app of which it has copied to the documents folder.

The only issue is that it isn't able to do so. The reason being that whenever it copies the app, the `JavaAppLauncher` which is found within the content of the mac app has changed from a unix executable to a regular TextEdit document and thus can't actually launch the app. However if I were to copy the app manually by copying it myself and not using the java program, there is no issue. I am not sure whether this issue is caused by my code, or whether it is just a general thing?

Important note, the .app does work when I just run the regular non copied version, but as soon as it is the copied version, which as been copied through Java it doesn't work because the change of the Unix executable.

```
public class LaunchProg {

    static String usernameMac2 = System.getProperty("user.name");

    static File propFile = new File (".");
    static String pathString = propFile.getAbsolutePath();
    static int pathhLeng = pathString.length();
    static int pathReaLeng = pathhLeng -1;
    static String filNamMac = "AppNam.app";
    static String pFPathRelMac = pathString.substring(0,pathReaLeng);

    private static final File fSourceMac = new File(pFPathRelMac);
    private static final File AppFold =  new File ("/Users/" + usernameMac2 + "/Documents");

    static File fileCret = new File("fCret.txt");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println(pFPathRelMac);
        launchMac();

    }

    static void launchMac() throws IOException {

        if (!fileCret.exists()){
            try {
                FileUtils.copyDirectory(fSourceMac, AppFold);
                PrintWriter pFW = new PrintWriter(fileCret);
                pFW.println("Created File For Check");
                pFW.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                String command = "open /Users/" + usernameMac2 + "/Documents/AppNam.app";
                Process staAp2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            }

        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that the `cp` command copies permissions, while your copy function doesn't.  So, the copy of the file does not have 'execute' permission.  That's why it appears as a TextEdit document, and that's why it cannot be run.  Try adding the 'execute' permission to the copy of the file.

Comment: @MikeNakis I appreciate the input, I fixed the issue by instead of copying the file, just moving the file. Using the following [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html)